# A question I answered seems to have been deleted

Tags: support, deleted-questions, auto-delete

From what I understand, based on my read of [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/12120/28900) and [this question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/16565/28900), a question with an upvoted answer cannot be auto-deleted or manually deleted by the poster, but one of those things seems to have happened....

Recently, a user was asking a question that basically amounted to "why don't we just plug in $\infty$ instead of taking limits." This brought to mind a similar sort of question--which, in its original formulation, asked why $\left(\frac{1+\infty}{\infty}\right)^\infty=e$--to which I (and several others) gave upvoted answers about two years ago. I seem to recall looking at it a few months back, but now I can't seem to find it. The OP's user account is still extant (though not active recently), but the question, itself, is nowhere to be found.

Any idea what could have happened?

Comment: [Déjà vu](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17513/is-it-possible-desirable-for-answers-to-be-preserved-when-a-highly-downvoted-que)

Comment: @Daniel: Oops! Forgot about that....

Answer (score 1):

The posts you link to concern *auto*-deletion and deletion by OP. However, posts can also be deleted by votes of 10k+ users (and moderators).

See [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) for details.

It is not uncommon that (closed) questions are deleted by votes of 10k+ users. Given your description of the question, it seems plausible that it was deleted by votes of 10k+ users.

Comment: +1: Hmmmm...that does seem plausible, though it would be a shame.

Comment: If you want to know for a fact it could help to mention the user that asked it (whom you seem to recall). In that case it would be easy for moderators to look it up. (To search for it among all your answers could be harder.)

Comment: Yep. Looks like it was indeed deleted by high-rep users (including you, hilariously).

Comment: Oh. I had no active recollection doing so, but the description felt somewhat familiar.